# Name That ...Name? 14

Tags: riddle, knowledge

My middle name is romantic which allows me to act

I'm not related to George, so I sing for a fact

I can be like a river in the Western world

And I am also really commonly hurled

Name the Name

Answer (score 10):

To resurrect this long-time unanswered question, I think the name which satisfies all four clues is:

> **JENNIFER**

*My middle name is romantic which allows me to act*

> [**Jennifer LOVE Hewitt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Love_Hewitt) is an actress (e.g. *I Know What You Did Last Summer*, *Ghost Whisperer* and many others...) with a romantic-sounding middle name.

*I'm not related to George, so I sing for a fact*

> [**Jennifer LOPEZ**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Lopez) shares a surname with the US comedian/actor [George Lopez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lopez), but is no relation. She is perhaps most renowned for her singing career, although she is also an actress.

*I can be like a river in the Western world*

> [**Jennifer HUDSON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Hudson) (another singer/actress) shares her surname with the [Hudson River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_River) in the northeastern US.

*And I am also really commonly hurled*

> [**Jennifer STONE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Stone) is a Disney Channel actress whose surname is an object that can be hurled or thrown.
>
>  (Alternatively, this part could clue a corruption of the name of the more famous US actress [**Jennifer ANISTON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Aniston), if we read her name as a soundalike-of-sorts for AND-I-STONE...)

Comment: Man, a 2 year old riddle finally getting solved :)